# What is $\mathbb{E} [ \| \mathcal{N}( 0 , \mathrm{Id}_n ) \|_\infty ]$?

Tags: probability-distributions, asymptotics, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N} (0 ,\mathrm{Id}_n )$ be an i.i.d. Gaussian vector. I am interested in result regarding the expected value of the supremum norm of $X$.

Here are my questions:

- What is know on the law of $\| X \|_\infty$?
- Is the value of $\mathbb{E} [\| X \|_\infty]$ know?
- At least, what is the asymptotic behavior of $\mathbb{E} [\| X \|_\infty]$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$?

*Remark.* More generally, I consider supremum norms of Gaussian random vectors $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma_n)$ where $\Sigma_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is invertible. The structure of $\Sigma_n$ (especially it's evolution with $n$) is not straightforward to describe, hence I first question the specific case $\Sigma_n = \mathrm{Id}_n$ but I am also curious if more general results for more general covariance are known.

*Edit:* Since $X$ is i.i.d., we easily see that, denoting $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$,
$$ \mathbb{P}( \| X \|_\infty \leq x ) = (\mathbb{P}( |Z| \leq x))^n = \mathrm{erf}(x)^n,$$
where $\mathrm{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^x \mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2} \mathrm{d} t$ is the error function. Hence,
$$\mathbb{E} [\| X \|_\infty] = \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P} ( \| X \|_\infty \geq x) \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^{\infty}(1 - \mathrm{erf}(x)^n) \mathrm{d} x.$$
Possibly this can help as a starting point.

Comment: Perhaps see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic ... "order statistic" where we find information about the distribution of the "largest" of a finite I.I.D. sequence.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed related. But I could not find precise answers to my questions.